# Virtual box crashes with undefined symbol

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

When executing Virtual Box through GUI doesn't pop up anything using terminal it crashed with error:

```
root@mayur-laptop:/home/mayur/Documents/MyOs# virtualbox
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZNK14QWidgetPrivate17hasHeightForWidthEv
```

I tried Google and came up with some solution to remove certain files

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtGui.so.4
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtCore.so.4
```

But it says

```
root@mayur-laptop:/home/mayur/Documents/MyOs# sudo rm /usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtGui.so.4
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtGui.so.4’: No such file or directory
root@mayur-laptop:/home/mayur/Documents/MyOs# sudo rm /usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtCore.so.4 
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtCore.so.4’: No such file or directory
```

P.S: I'am using trusty with xbunutu
Edit : I found out the location of libraries which I was trying to delete but I feel unsafe to delete them it may arise problems perhaps.